# How well would shell/bash handling of interface input scale?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, serial-port

Here is the situation:

I have an interface which communicates encoded sensor data (a one line string with newline character) exactly every minute. This is mapped to /dev/tty100. I've set up a java webserver which interprets the data when it's sent, and a very simple bash script (think catting the port)), grabbing each line of input as a variable and sending it as a POST request with CURL.

My gut feeling is that relying on a bash script to read from the port is hacky, but it seems to work a lot better than trying to listen to serial events from unreliable 3rd party Java libraries. Hypothetically we may want to start adding a lot more interfaces/data on each interface, which means I need to know how this will perform in scale. My thought for that would be have a new script running for every interface, each one sending each line of data to the webserver.

So, my question is, in a production environment with multiple interfaces or possibly more data per minute over each port, do you think this is a feasible approach, or is there a more professional way to go about this?

Comment: At best, you'll have one `bash` process monitoring every tty and a separate `curl` process for each POST. You almost certainly will want a single process that can read from one (or multiple) ttys and do the POST within the same process.

Comment: What about the 3rd party libraries is unreliable?  It could be that the serial port settings are set incorrectly.

Comment: The problem is the interface is an emulated serial port, so the data comes in on /dev/tty100, which is then mapped to serial /dev/ttyS100. The interface itself is prone to crashing for a variety of reasons I won't get into, and requires the interface software to be reinitialized. The serial libraries for Java however (the predecessor of RXTX), as far as I can tell can't figure this out - once the port goes down it can't receive data even when the port is reinitialized. Our only recourse until now has been to restart the whole JVM - which is why I wanted to handle the serial outside Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Java libraries for sensor stuff; but I think it is fair to say: **bash** provides a **scripting** interface; suited for **scripting** administrative tasks.

The bash language might allow you to write "real applications" but: that is not its main purpose. In other words: one would need A) a lot of **discipline** and B) a very high degree of knowledge about bash in order to create an **application** in that scripting language.

Meaning: maybe you can manage to "scale" your solution performance-wise; but I somehow doubt that it will scale from an "software engineering" point of view. Chances are, that sooner or later, your script degenerates into something that only few people understand, and even less people will dare to modify.

You see, when you use any "higher level" language, like Java, C++, python, ... you have a lot of additional tooling at hand (for example nice unit test frameworks) that help you to maintain your application over time.

Comment: True, which is why I've done as much as we can in Java. The bash script is merely passing the data to Java in a more convenient format - since the Java libraries for handling interfaces are -terrible- that I've seen. Literally all the script is (and will ever be) is; 

"For each line of data, run this curl command to send the data to a webserver"

Java then operates on it from there in much more depth.